# How to autoload a module subroutine?

Tags: module, autoload, raku

In Perl 5,  a module can declare an [`AUTOLOAD()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading) subroutine that will be called if an undefined subroutine is called. Similarly in Perl 6 classes there is a [`FALLBACK()`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-FALLBACK_%28method%29) method. But I could not find anything similar to `FALLBACK()` for modules.

Here is an example of a use case: I would like to write a new module `MyModule` that exports all subroutines that another module `OtherModule` exports, and then forwards all subroutine calls to those exported methods (not yet defined) in `MyModule` to the corresponding subroutine in `OtherModule`. I think I can get the exported symbols from `OtherModule` using [`CompUnit::Util`](https://github.com/LLFourn/p6-CompUnit-Util).

**Question**: How can I implement the Perl 5 autoload mechanism in Perl 6?

Answer (score 4):

Lexical names are resolved statically, so I'm not sure how to implement `AUTOLOAD` without some deep magic.

Regarding your specific example, I'm also not quite sure what the 'proper' way to do so would be, but here's a 'dirty' solution that seems to work, replacing a sub `&foo` exported by a module `Foo`:

```
# get all subroutines exported by Foo by default
BEGIN my @reex = do {
    use Foo;
    MY::.pairs.grep(*.key.starts-with('&'));
}

# export our replacement subroutine (also in the default namespace)
sub foo is export {
    say "new foo";
}

# re-export subroutines lacking a replacement
# placed at the end of the module so EXPORT will have been populated
BEGIN EXPORT::DEFAULT::{.key} //= .value
    for @reex;
```